# Modulo gives unexpected result

Tags: java

I have some problem with numerator, denumerator and modulo. 7 / 3 = 2.3333333333 gives me a modulo of 1!? Must be some wrong? I study a non-objective ground level course, so my code is simple and I have simplified the code below. (Some lines are in swedish)

Calling the method:

```
 // Anropar metod och presenterar beräkning av ett bråktal utifrån täljare och nämnare
int numerator = 7;
int denumerator = 3;
System.out.println("Bråkberäkning med täljare " + numerator + " och nämnare " + denumerator + " ger " + fraction(numerator,denumerator));
```

And the method:

```
// Metod för beräkning av bråktal utifrån täljare och nämnare
public static String fraction(int numerator, int denumerator) {
    // Beräkning
    int resultat1 = numerator / denumerator;
    int resultat2 = numerator % denumerator;
    return Integer.toString(resultat1) + " rest " + Integer.toString(resultat2);
}
```

Comment: 7 is 2 * 3 __+1__, so what's strange about having 1 for the modulo ?

Comment: The divisor of a fraction is called "denominator" and the language is called "Java" - sorry for being pedantic, but unfortunately, programming is all about attention to detail :-(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

3 goes into 7 twice with 1 left over.  The answer is supposed to be 1. That's what [modulo means](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation).

Comment: OK, but i thouhgt I should get the other rest.33333?

Comment: @3D-kreativ if you want the fractional part, simply divide (using floating point, of course) the modulo by the denominator.  `float fractional = (float)resultat1 / denominator;`.  Note that if you do this using integer division your result will be 0 (since it's always less than 1).

Answer (score 1):

7 modulo 3 gives 1. Since 7 = 2*3 + 1.

Answer (score 1):

```
7 % 3 = 1
```

Just as expected. If you want the `.3333` you could take the modulo and devide it by your denominator to get `1 / 3 = 0.3333`

Or do `(7.0 / 3.0) % 1 = 0.3333`

Answer (score 0):

Ehm 7 % 3 = 1

What would you expect?

*Given two positive numbers, a (the dividend) and n (the divisor), a modulo n (abbreviated as a mod n) can be thought of as the remainder, on division of a by n. For instance, the expression "5 mod 4" would evaluate to 1 because 5 divided by 4 leaves a remainder of 1, while "9 mod 3" would evaluate to 0 because the division of 9 by 3 leaves a remainder of 0; there is nothing to subtract from 9 after multiplying 3 times 3. (Notice that doing the division with a calculator won't show you the result referred to here by this operation, the quotient will be expressed as a decimal.) When either a or n is negative, this naive definition breaks down and programming languages differ in how these values are defined. Although typically performed with a and n both being integers, many computing systems allow other types of numeric operands.*

More info : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation

Answer (score 0):

you didn't do a question!

And if your question is just:

"...gives me a modulo of 1!? Must be some wrong?"

No, it isn't, 7/3 = 2, and has a modulo of 1. Since (3 * 2) + 1 = 7.

Answer (score 0):

`%` for ints does not give the decimal fraction but the remainder from the division.  Here it is from 6 which is the highest multiplum of 2 lower than your number 7.  7-6 is 1.

Comment: Not correct. % gives a result with fraction if the operands are floating-point.

Comment: Exactly. Your answer doesn't contain any such qualification. It gives the impression that % behaves that way in all cases.

Comment: @EJP, sure, if that confuses you.

Comment: I would think it would confuse anybody coming onto it cold. Obviously it didn't confuse me but thanks for the thought.

Answer (score 0):

A modulo operator will give you the reminder of a division. Therefore, it is normal that you get the number 1 as a result.

Also, note that you are using integers... `7/3 != 2.3333333333`.

One last thing, be careful with that code. A division by zero would make your program crash. `;)`

Answer (score 0):

You are using integer operands so you get an integer result. That's how the language works.